# How can output of "copy rotation constraint" be accessed?

Tags: python, rigging

[image]
Object **C** has copy rotation constraint and is copying rotation from **A** and **B**

When i rotate objects  **A** and **B**  target object **C** rotates but the Transform does not show the resultant rotation values.

**Q1:** Where dose the resultant rotation values are show?

**Q2:** Can they be accessed through python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use the world matrix.**

On Q2 `target_object.matrix_world.to_euler()` will give you the resulting Euler rot, which could be used in a panel to ans Q1 part.

Example script using the panel template.

```
import bpy
from math import degrees

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the object context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.active_object
        col = layout.column()
        mw = obj.matrix_world
        euler_rot = mw.to_euler()
        for axis in "xyz":
            col.label(text="%c : %7.4f" % (axis, degrees(getattr(euler_rot, axis, 0))))

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 1):

@ batFINGER Thank you

I wanted it to know bone constraints resultant value and with a bit fidgeting batFINGER code i got this.

If some one can generalize this code to work for any object, bone etc that wold be awesome. But my problem is solved.

```
import bpy
from math import degrees

## changed class name to avoid duplicate class
class LayoutDemoPanelBone(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the object context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo Bone"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_layout_Bone"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "bone" ## changed here

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.selected_pose_bones[0] ## changed here i don't know if there is active pose bone method
        col = layout.column()
        mw = obj.matrix ## changed here
        euler_rot = mw.to_euler()
        for axis in "xyz":
            col.label("%c : %7.4f" % (axis, degrees(getattr(euler_rot, axis, 0))))

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanelBone)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanelBone)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```