# Accessing the new rotation caused by "Track To" constraint

Tags: python, constraints, tracking

So after searching for quite a while how to have my camera focus some specific object while the camera moves through space I found the very easy solution of the "Track To" object constraint.

This constraint does the job just fine, but now I wanted to extract the "new" rotation of the camera after being moved and still focusing the target and stumbled upon the problem.

**After being moved, the tracking camera object's rotation isn't updated. Is there a way to access thew new rotation due to the "Track To" constraint?**

I did not add a minimal example as it's less about a specific problem or a blend file and more about the nature of the Track To constraint. I did search the constraint's features, but none seem to give the actual rotation.
I would prefer to access the rotation through the Python API but if you point me to where it's in the GUI, I'm sure I can figure out the rest on my own.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [`ObjectMatrixWorld.to_euler()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.to_euler)

*Proof using the console:*

```
>>> C.active_object.matrix_world.to_euler()
Euler((1.5707963705062866, -0.0, 0.0), 'XYZ')
>>> import math
>>> math.degrees(1.5707963705062866)
90.00000250447813
```

- Further reading: [Incorrect matrix_world after transformation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27667/31447)
- API link: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix
- Custom panel example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/66941/31447

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to be exactly what I searched for. I was unaware of the object's matrix components, the object rotation components were a bit of a red hering, I guess.